# How to prevent re render in react switch button after change button state

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have a text field and its default state is false and the text field is disabled. And After I clicked react switch button my text field is enabled and its state change to true. But After I navigate another page and go back to my previous page, my tex field is disabled again and its states are set to false. But I don't need that. I need to stop re-render my switch and text field after going to another page. How Can I do this...?
**If You can help me..It's mean a lot. Thank You**.

```
//Switch State
const [openSwitch, setOpenSwitch] = useState({
    checkedA: true,
    checkedB: false,
});

//Text field state
const [disable, setDisable] = useState(true);


// Switch Handler
const switchHandler = (event) => {
    setOpenSwitch({...openSwitch, [event.target.name]: 
event.target.checked});
    setDisable(!disable);
};


//Switch function
        <Switch
             checked={openSwitch.checkedB}
             onChange={switchHandler}
             color="primary"
             name="checkedB"
             inputProps={{'aria-label': 'primary checkbox'}}
          />

//Text field
   <Autocomplete 
     disabled={disable}
    >
  </Autocomplete>
```

This is default :
[image]

This is the way I need to set after going back another page:
[image]

Comment: If you are using `redux`, you can set the state to `redux`. But another solution can be `localStorage`

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem of re rendering by moving between pages your component will get mounted and unmounted again. When you move back to the page it is like a new component is rendered and in the new component your default state of disable is false.

There is multiple ways to fix this you can pass the state manager to where you start the routing like the app component:

```
const App = () => {
    const [inputDisable, setInputDisable] = useState(false);
    
    ...

    return (
        ...
            <YourComponent disable={inputDisable} setDisable={setInputDisable}/>
        ...
    );
};
```

But this is not a good practice. You can use React Context in order to fix your problem and you can also use state management libraries like Redux. These are better ways and I recommend learning both of them

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and standard way of storing the global state for the functional components is using the Context.

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).